# use git repository on mac

Tags: macos, git, repository

I am novice using Git repository and I have some questions. I have downloaded git to Mac and I have done a commit of one of my projects. This commit is locally in my computer? How can I access to this repository from other computer or is there some tool to make a repository in a server that only I can access. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This commit is locally in my computer?

Yes. You would need to push it to a bare repo in order for said commit to be visible by anyone having access to that remote repo.

The simplest way to have said access is through a shared folder.

Otherwise, for remote repo managed by a server, you would need a listener in order to allow other users to clone your remote repo (or for you to push to it).
That listener can be a git daemon, ssh or https. See [Git Protocols](http://git-scm.com/book/ch4-1.html) for more.